# Page views mysql

Tags: codeigniter

Codeigniter I want to increase +1 when loading page. but the query does 0

'views + 1' and I did 10 no problem.

It didn't make sense to throw the query for views.

```
function get_views()
{
    $this->db->set('views', 'views+1');
    $this->db->where('Id', 1);
    $this->db->update('pages'); // gives UPDATE mytable SET field = field+1 WHERE id = 2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a third parameter as `false` like below:

```
$this->db->set('views', 'views+1', FALSE);
```

The Third Parameter tells CodeIgniter not to protect the generated query with backticks. In your case the final query will be

```
UPDATE pages SET views = views + 1 WHERE Id = '1';
```